Stripper assassin and a ghetto-blaster
The scene I remember is what looks like an older businessman is sitting behind a desk when a tall, statuesque blonde comes in and puts down a ghetto-blaster. She starts dancing/stripping to the music and when she's down to her underwear (stockings etc.) , she produces a gun and shoots/kills the businessman. Anyone remember the movie? I'd say it was an 80s flick. 
I think the gun was taped to the back of the ghetto-blaster (a large boombox used to play loud music). Unfortunately, I can't remember any more about the film.
It wasn't a 'spoof' type movie but an 'action' film.
On checking the net it may be one of those late 80s early 90s Andy Sidaris films. He done a whole series of fairly low-budget action movies mainly featuring good-looking women and big guns/explosions (e.g. Hard Hunted).
Having bought a cheap set of Andy Sidaris films and gone through them (quite good fun) it's not an Andy Sidaris film. Only other detail I can think of that it was a tall, statuesque white woman in a (I think) silvery grey two piece formal business looking attire (skirt and jacket). I still think late 80s or 90s and definitely not the Naked Weapon flick suggested here. Pretty sure it was an all/mostly European cast. Possibly something in the Cynthia Rothrock kind of genre?

"she produces a gun" Where does she get it from?

Can you add some more details? This is extremely vague.

some kind of flashdance spoof?

The scene you are talking about is in the movie Naked Weapon.
Reason: The stripper strips until only lingerie is left on her body and then produces a gun and assassinates the person as the scene you've mentioned in the question. Plus its a complete action flick.

Is this a comment about a similar scene in a different movie or an answer? If it's meant to be an answer, you may want to explain your reasoning.

If you are talking about the 2002 Hong Kong flick Naked Weapon then you must confuse it with something else, because there is no such scene in the movie. At one point Maggie Q goes to a "client", drops her coat and has sex with him on the bed, but he draws a gun on her (because it's a trap), and she kills him with her hand. There is also no ghetto blaster.
